# docker-compose tries to access registry v1 on first "up"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

I have a docker-compose file that looks like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  registry:
    restart: always
    image: registry:2
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    environment:
      REGISTRY_STORAGE: "s3"
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ACCESSKEY: "yada"
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_SECRETKEY: "yada"
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_REGION: "us-east-1"
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET: "docker-registry"
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ENCRYPT: "true"
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_SECURE: "true"
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_V4AUTH: "true"
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_CHUNKSIZE: "5242880"
   volumes:
     - ./data:/data

 prototype:
    restart: always
    image: localhost:5000/prototype
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    volumes:
      - /opt/config:/config
    depends_on:
      - registry
```

The weird thing is on the first run the compose file tries to pull from registry v1, not v2.  On the second run, everything works fine.  I was hoping the "depends_on" would prevent this. Am I doing something wrong here?

First run:

```
# docker-compose up
Starting docker_registry_1
Recreating docker_prototype_1
Pulling prototype (localhost:5000/prototype:latest)...
Pulling repository localhost:5000/prototype
ERROR: Error while pulling image: Get http://localhost:5000/v1/repositories/prototype/images: read tcp [::1]:35416->[::1]:5000: read: connection reset by peer
```

Note the "v1" in the URL.

Second run:

```
# docker-compose up
docker_registry_1 is up-to-date
Recreating 9a743a171c84_docker_prototype_1
Pulling prototype (localhost:5000/prototype:latest)...
latest: Pulling from prototype
a3ed95caeb02: Already exists
3286cdf780ef: Already exists
...and so on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what might be happening is that the registry is not actually ready to serve requests by the time compose tries to start the second service. `depends_on` only applies an order, it doesn't actually wait for the previous services to be "ready", because it has no way of knowing what "ready" actually means.

I believe the reason that it's hitting the v1 URL is because docker starts by trying v2, when that fails it goes to try v1, and the error that gets raised is on the second attempt.

I would suggest decoupling these services into two separate Compose files. One to run the registry, and one to run an application that depends on the registry. You can healthcheck the registry before launching the application.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, thank you!  For those following along at home, I ended up breaking the docker-compose into two files, starting the registry first, and then polling the endpoint like so in the Bash script:

`while ! ( nmap -Pn -p5000 127.0.0.1 | grep -q open )
do
   printf "Registry is not ready yet...\n"
        sleep 1
done
printf "Registry is ready!\n"`

And then starting the microservice